# conditional probability of endig up in a specific set

Tags: probability

Assume we have three initial sets $\mathcal{A},\mathcal{B},\mathcal{C}$ and 4 final sets $\mathrm{A},\mathrm{B},\mathrm{C},\mathrm{X}$.
If I know that an element of $\mathcal{A}$ can only end up with probability $a$ in $\mathrm{A}$ and with probability $(1-a)$ in $\mathrm{X}$. An element from $\mathcal{B}$ can only end up with probability $b$ in $\mathrm{B}$ and with prob. $(1-b)$ in $\mathrm{X}$. And finally an element in $\mathcal{C}$ can either end up with $p_1$ in $\mathrm{A}$, with $p_2$ in $\mathrm{B}$, with $p_3$ in $\mathrm{X}$ or with probability $1-p_1-p_2-p_3$ in $\mathrm{C}$.

I am a bit confused on what the conditional probability is:
$$\mathbb{P}(i \in \mathcal{C} \; \text{ends up in}\; \mathrm{C} \mid X=\{\})$$
Is it $$\frac{1-(p_1+p_2+p_3)}{\mathbb{P}(X=\{\})}$$ or $$\frac{1-(p_1+p_2)}{\mathbb{P}(X=\{\})}$$ since we have that the set X is empty and therefore also no node from $\mathcal{C}$ can be in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first answer is correct by a direct application of Bayes theorem.

P (i ends up in C | X empty) = P (X empty | i ends up in C) * P(i ends up in C ) / P( X empty )

What is not present in your expression is P( X empty | i ends up in C ) = 1, but that does not change the result.